# <WebMethod()> attribute changes from 2.0 to 3.5

Tags: json, asmx, webmethod

I have a method that looks like:

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function Search(ByVal q As String) As String
```

Updating from .net 2.0 to 3.5 appears to have broken this.

We're doing data.split() on the value returned, and that's generating a error - it looks like the value returned is now a json structure, not a simple string.

Is there a way to revert to the prior behavior?

Comment: What do you mean "broken"? Be specific. .NET 3.5 is still using CLR 2.0, and there were very few breaking changes to ASMX web services.

Comment: Broken in that prior to the update, we were doing data.split() with the returned value, and now it fails with a "not implemented" error.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to import System.Web.Script.Services

Then, try adding this attribute:

```
<WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Xml)> _
```

How are you calling the web method? Through javascript?

Comment: Be sure to specify a dataType param in your ajax methods. If you don't specify jquery will guess. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: dataType is "json" - we're getting a json structure back, but apparently prior to updating to 3.5, it was a simple string.  Trying to verify that this was a change between 2.0 and 3.5, and see if there's a way to revert to the prior behavior, or present evidence that we'll need to update our js calls.

Comment: 2.0 wouldn't know how to return json (unless you had the extensions via ajaxtoolkit), so you weren't getting json. Just use success: function(data) and data.d to get your string.

Comment: I just tried changing my site target to 2.0, and I get xml by default. Not sure how you got a string before. perhaps post your jquery code

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue. With the basic setup of Webmethod and jquery ajax call with 2.0 it returns a string (type string in js) or string array (type object in js), in 3.5 it always returns an object and the actual data returned is under .d when returning a primitive like a string or string array.

My best solution so far was a javascript method to check for .d.

```
    function getResponse(r){
        if(r.d!=null){
            return r.d;
        }else{
            return r;
        }
    }
```

I have to support both the 2.0 and 3.5 calls for the transition and would rather not have to expend too much energy as 2.0 will be gone soon.

But I would rather a better solution.